# Upload de Imagem com Firebase e React Native usando RN Image-picker

Tags: imagem, upload, firebase, react-native

Estou usando o componente react-native-image-picker para capturar uma imagem que deve ser salva no firebase. 
Estou usando o seguinte código:

`firebaseApp.storage().ref('/images/').child('teste')                    .putString(response.data, 'base64')`

response.data retorna uma string base64, mas o firebase me retorna o erro apresentado na imagem abaixo:

[image: Erro ao fazer upload para o firebase]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algumas vezes arquivos base64 vem com barras de espaço desnecessárias inseridos pelo plugin e/ou framework que você esta usando. A SDK do Storage é sensível a estes erros e não consegue executar algumas de suas funções internas. Para resolver este bug você precisa remover estes espaços em branco.

Segundo [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695988/dom-exception-5-invalid-character-error-on-valid-base64-image-string-in-javascri) postagem, tente utilizar esta função antes de passar para o storage

```
function decodeFromBase64(input) {
 input = input.replace(/\s/g, '');
 return atob(input);
}
```